# tkinterをpyenv上で使用できるようにしたい

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

でシステム標準のPython3でimportはできたものの、pyenv環境（python3.5.2）ではimportできません．

pyenv環境でもtkinterのモジュールをimportする方法を教えてください．
また、matplotlibと併用して使用したいです．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の手順で解決したという[報告があります](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358646/4368502)。

- まず`pyenv`の Python をアンインストールする: `pyenv uninstall 3.4.2`
- `tk-dev`パッケージをインストールする:  `sudo apt install tk-dev`
- `pyenvl`の Python を再インストールする: `pyenv install 3.4.2`

少し情報が古いかもしれませんが、現在のバージョンで試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

---

（個人的には通常用途で`pyenv`は必要ないと思っています）

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事、pyenv環境でも実行することができました。